# PHP WebService cannot be used in VS2012

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, web-reference

I have developed a WebService in PHP using SoapDiscovery class made by Braulio José Solano Rojas but with some adjustments made by me in order to support complex types.

The problem is that I can use the webservice in PHP client, but not in VS 2012. When adding the Web reference, Web Service methods are detected and I can add the reference correctly, but when I try to use it, intellisense does not show it, so that I cannot instantiate it and do nothing. I can, however, use a Webservice that does not use complex types.

The WSDL is at: http://feriados.servicios.desytec.com/feriados?wsdl

Please advise me.

Comment: Why did you use a web reference instead of a service reference? Also, see http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/ to learn how to find where the code went.

Comment: because it is a web service.... I have another web service that does not have complex types and it works.

Comment: You should always use service references. Web references are part of the legacy ASMX technology, which should not be used for new development.

Comment: I tried it, but I cannot use the service either. It does not even appear in Object Browser

Comment: Again, look at the link I posted to figure out where your Reference.cs/.vb is located; then look inside to find the code.

Comment: Reference.cs appears empty. Only the comments telling that is an auto-generated code is inside.

Comment: Ok, then try using svcutil.exe from the command line, to see what errors come back.

Comment: in fact... there are 3 errors... the first one is: wdsl:portType cannot be imported. A schema with the namespace "urn:Desytec_Feriados" cannot be found. The only difference f this webservice with respect to a webservice that does work, is that in this case, complex types are being defined.

Comment: And, is there a schema with that namespace?

Comment: Ok, that's just wrong. You have `complexType` outside of any `schema`

Comment: Yes.. that was the problem... however, due to this correction, I realized also that array type is defined bad... well... that will be for another question.

Comment: And finally, I was able to create an instance of the Webservice from a Visual Studio application, however, at the moment of invocation, a "Moved Permanently" error is thrown. Do you know how to solve it?